# Slicing values in a column to make a condition for another column

Tags: python, pandas, slice

So I have `df1` which has this particular column :

```
X_codes
-----------------------------------                                    
A4529,B5243,E5170
-----------------------------------      
A7413,A7260,E5164         
-----------------------------------          
F6032
```

On the other hand, I have `df2` that has this column :

```
act
---
A
---
B
---
C
---
D
---
E
---
F
```

So the result that I want is :

```
X_codes                             | A | B | C | D | E | F | 
----------------------------------- |---|---|---|---|---|---|                
A4529,B5243,E5170                   | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
----------------------------------- |---|---|---|---|---|---|
A7413,A7260,E5164                   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
----------------------------------- |---|---|---|---|---|---|
F6032                               | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

I tried to do so using explode : `df1.assign(X_codes=df1.X_codes.str.split(",")).explode('X_codes')`
And then apply a lambda filter for each letter, but it took awhile (because I have over 18M rows), so I'd like a faster method if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question. It is not clear what you do with or use `df2`. Info about the indices would be useful and also posting the 'and then apply...' code would be helpful. As for now it seems that you just want to add a new column to `df2`, for instance.

Comment: maybe you could try using `new_df = df1.assign({letter: X_codes.str.contains(letter) for letter in df2.values.flatten()})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace` and `str.get_dummies`

```
df.join(df.X_codes.str.replace('\w+', lambda g: g.group(0)[0]).str.get_dummies(',')
          .reindex(df2.act, axis=1,fill_value=0))

Out[749]:
             X_codes  A  B  C  D  E  F
0  A4529,B5243,E5170  1  1  0  0  1  0
1  A7413,A7260,E5164  1  0  0  0  1  0
2              F6032  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: @ScottBoston: The use of callable in `replace` is not popular. I want to try something different, so I use it. Yours is cleaner and more readable :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(df.join(df['X_codes'].str.split(',')
                      .explode().str[0]
                      .str.get_dummies()
                      .max(level=0)
                      .reindex(df2['act'], 
                               axis=1, 
                               fill_value=0)))
```

Output:

```
             X_codes  A  B  C  D  E  F
0  A4529,B5243,E5170  1  1  0  0  1  0
1  A7413,A7260,E5164  1  0  0  0  1  0
2              F6032  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Details:

Skip the join we'll come back to joining results back to original dataframe at the end.
First, let's split and explode 'X_codes' to create a pandas Series for X_codes, then use `str[0]` shortcut for `.str.get(0)` to get the first letter from X_codes.
Next, call `.str.get_dummies` and reindex with df2['acts'] and fill missing values with 0.  Groupby by index level=0, return the max by column and join back to original dataframe.